# Assignment user with "select" helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want add Users asssignment to Projects model.
By default it passing user_id: 1 (id of admin, only one who can create projects).

I need selectbox with list of all users and when I select id/name that differ from id: 1, I need project to change user_id to one that was selected from the box.

```
   =form_for [@user, @project] do |f|
      = render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object

      =f.label :title
      =f.text_field :title

      =f.label :content
      =f.text_area :content

      =f.label :budget
      =f.text_area :budget

      = f.label :user_id
      = f.select(:user_id, [['First user', 1], ['Second user', 2]])

      =f.submit "Make it perfect", class: "btn btn-small btn-inverse"
```

"First user" and "Second user" its test data.I can manually change user_id from rails console but when I submitting form with changed value, it doesn't save it and reverse user_id to default(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which rails version?

If 3.*? check

```
 attr_accessible
```

in model.

if rasil 4.*
check

```
 permitted parameters
```

in controller